# Can Verisign signtool sign jar files in windows enviornment?

Tags: sign, signtool, verisign

I used the following command:

```
C:\Verisign>signtool sign /v /ac "MSCV-VSClass3.cer"/s  MY /n "ABC Company LTD" /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll  TestRun.jar
```

and I get the following result:

```
SignTool Error: This file format cannot be signed because it is not recognized.
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue? Does VeriSign not support signing jars?

Answer (score 0):

No, signtool doesn't know how to sign JAR files. It knows how to sign a few Microsoft known formats, such as PE, CAB, and MSI - but not JAR.

To sign a JAR file on Windows, use Oracle's [jarsigner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html) tool. A verisign certificate will work, you just need to use a different tool that actually does the signing.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I already have a security certificate from VeriSign to sign EXEs. I need to use this certificate with jarsigner.

Comment: @user1606275 the link in the answer I wrote is the best documentation for it I could find.